# Regex practicing groups

Tags: regex, vb.net

Hello again Stack Overflow. As i mentioned in my last post i am trying to get better at regular expressions. I am going through my books chapters tonight and decided to see if i could, if even possible create multiple groups. I am fully aware Regex is not the answer to everything this is purely for me to learn. I am Using VB.net

Example input(s):

```
MyTokenName{%@example1%, %@example2%}
MyTokenName{example1, example2}
```

Now this is a completed made up by myself output to test against. The consistent factors of this expression are `Name{ }` There will always be a name consisting of only `a-z` first. Inside of curly brackets. The MAIN delimiter that separates the Two groups is `,` Before the groups start there will be an OPTIONAL `%@` that ends with a OPTIONAL `%`

So to summarize i only want to match groups defined between the curly brackets of only `a-z` unlimited times.

```
MyTokenName{%@example%, %@example%} ----- Would match Two groups example1 and example2
MyTokenName{example, example} --- Would match Two groups example1 and example2
```

My attempt that's not working.

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z]+\{[^a-zA-Z@]+?)[a-zA-Z, ]+(?=%?})
```

Any advice would be amazing. Thanks guys for such a great forum. Please remember i am only trying to practice regex. I can do this with other .Net methods.

Comment: Would there always be only 2 groups ?

Comment: Well it's just me practicing so i'm going to say yes there will always be Two groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting way could maybe this one:

```
/(?i)(?<=\{|\G|\{%@|\G%@)([a-z0-9]+)(?:%?\s*(?:,\s*|\}))/g
```

http://regex101.com/r/bU0zY5

Here's also a structural view of it:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/PfVUP8VsjV7agvsZ)

with interesting I mean the usage of lookbehind with `\G` ;) and it should match all your `example`s

Comment: Wow you really put some thought in that. More importantly i now know Two more great sites. I'm going to try now but is there a way to add a group also to match the MyTokenName also.

Comment: (?i)(?<=([a-z]+)\{|\G|\{%@|\G%@)([a-z0-9]+)(?:%?\s*(?:,\s*|\}))

Ignores the first name which i cant work out why :/

Comment: `(?<=([a-z]+)` ??? I assume there's the problem. It's not possible to use Lookbehinds with an unfixed length

Comment: This actually confuses me, Just by playing around if i replaced % with a couple of new chars(-->) it fails (?:-->?\s*(?:,\s*|\]))

Comment: you cannot use patterns with variable lengths (`\s*`) within lookbehinds (`(?<=.....)`), this could be your problem

Answer (score 1):

This variable length lookbehind is expensive performance wise and of no real value in this case, when all you want to do is capture what your interrested in.

This might work.

`[a-zA-z]+ { \s*(?:%@)? ([a-z]+) %?\s* , \s*(?:%@)? ([a-z]+) %?\s* }`

Answer (score 0):

Does the pattern `(\w+)` serve your purpose here?
It'll match MyTokenName, example1, and example2 in both sample cases.

If you always wanted to ignore MyTokenName you could just refer to any matches other than the first match in the list.

Like:

```
dim txt = "MyTokenName{%@example1%, %@example2%}"
dim matches = regex.matches(txt,"(\w+)")
for i as integer = 1 to (matches.count - 1)
    DoSomethingWith(matches(i).value) 'start at 1 so we skip over MyTokenName
next
```

Something like that.

Comment: I feel really useless now like every thing iv learn't meant nothing.

Comment: It's all a part of learning! It's good that you're challenging yourself to apply your knowledge. Keep it up!

Comment: Sam, what were those 4 paragraph's in the question?

Comment: This answer doesn't take account in any of the requirements stated in the question, this will also match `foobarlol` and a lot of other strings. @SamJohnson So if this is the answer you were looking for you didn't even need to write that long question with all those requirements.